# Why can't I get convolution to work properly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, convolution

Convolving signals in MATLAB produces unexpected results every time. Take the following code for example, in which I attempt to convolve a `rect` function with itself:

```
clc

clear all

x=-5:.01:5;

y=rectangularPulse(x);

C=conv(y,y);

plot(C)
```

Producing a triangle function is correct, however it should be centered at 0, not 1000, and the amplitude should be 1, not 100. I'm sure this is just a simple misunderstanding of how the `conv()` function works in MATLAB; if there's a way to do it that would produce a triangle function that gos from -1 to 1 with an amplitude of 1 please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the confusion here is that the signal `y` that you are dealing with is discrete with its samples spaced out by `0.01` in `x`. Additionally [`CONV`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) appears to pull double-duty for polynomial multiplication. From the help docs:

> If u and v are vectors of polynomial coefficients, convolving them is equivalent to multiplying the two polynomials.

[Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) involves computing the area under the intersecting curves as you slide one across the other. `CONV` does the discrete version of this by simply multiplying overlapping sample points and essentially assuming a value of 1 for the distance between samples (i.e. the width of the rectangular strips approximating the area under the curve). To get a true convolution, you have to scale the resulting approximate area by the sample spacing of `0.01`. Additionally, you will want to extract the central part of the convolution using the `'same'` argument so you can plot the results versus `x`, like so:

```
C = 0.01.*conv(y, y, 'same');
plot(x, C);
```

[image]